# how to call a method having nullable parameter in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method with two nullable int parameter.I want to pass one parameter and another one I want to pass null.I searched in google but I did not found any proper answer for this. Can anyone help me. below is one sample method, how can I call CallNullable method.

```
 public void CallNullable(int? x, int? y)
 {
     int z = (x.HasValue ? x.Value : 0) + (y.HasValue ? y.Value : 0);
 }
```

Comment: Side note: `x.HasValue ? x.Value : 0` is equal to `x ?? 0` so you can simplify your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call them just like you would call a method accepting non-nullable values of the same type (with the exception being that you can use a `null` value)

```
public void Main()
{
    CallNullable(23, null);
}

public void CallNullable(int? x, int? y)
{
    int z = (x.HasValue ? x.Value : 0) + (y.HasValue ? y.Value : 0);
}
```

By the way (warning, this may be confusing if you're just starting to program), you can use the [**null-coalescing (??) operator**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) to simplify your code a bit:

```
public void CallNullable(int? x, int? y)
{
   int z = (x ?? 0) + (y ?? 0);
}
```

`??` uses the value on the left side of the operator if it **is not** null, otherwise it uses the one on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 public void CallNullable(int? x, int? y)
    {
        int z = (x.HasValue ? x.Value : 0) + (y.HasValue ? y.Value : 0);
    }
```

You can Call like this

```
 int? i=2;
 int? b=1;
 CallNullable(i, b);
```